# Is there a good way to vertically center text without using display:table-cell on the parent?

Tags: html, css

It's a very common situation: a designer tells me that some piece of text should  be vertically centered, but I can't use the display:table-cell; hack because the containing element **needs** to have a different display `property`. I also don't want to have to use any `position:absolute` due to the problems that presents.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z824m656/1/

HTML

```
<div class="contents-vertically-centerd">
  <img src="https://blog.stackoverflow.com/images/wordpress/stackoverflow-logo-300.png" width="150"/><span>Here's some text that I want vertically centered with respect to the image</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.contents-vertically-centerd { padding: 10px; border: 1px dashed #000000; }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to align text vertically center in div with CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-align-text-vertically-center-in-div-with-css)

Answer (score 1):

You need to vertically align the image, not the text.

Have you tried:

```
div img {
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

In the kind of situation you describe, it will also assist you if you:

- explicitly declare the `height` of the image
- declare the `display` of the `<span>` text as `inline-block`
- explicitly declare the `height` of the `<span>`
- explicitly declare the `line-height` of the `<span>`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an updated fiddle using `vertical-align: middle;` 
https://jsfiddle.net/z824m656/2/

```
div.contents-vertically-centerd * {
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vertical-align: middle` but keep in mind this only aligns `inline` (or `inline-block` content). So it should go like:

```
div.contents-vertically-centerd img, div.contents-vertically-centerd span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your special use case, there’s a simple solution: Use `vertical-align: middle` on the image. It will center the text to the image. [Here’s the updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nLe508bs/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is the `transform: translateY(-50%)` method.

```
.element {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  
  /* Used to center horizontally */
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>This text is vertically centered.</p>
</div>
```

A more detailed write-up [here](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/).